# Javascript code only effects drop-down menu links for some reason

Tags: javascript

Edit: I am also okay with doing it through CSS if that is possible. Also, note that a:active will not work because a:active only changes the element / link for a brief moment while it is active, it does not change it until another link in the navigation bar is clicked.

I'm trying to write a code where, in the navigation bar, if a link is clicked and while the link links to the current page, the link color in the navigation bar should be different (should change to red from white). So far, here is my html.

```
<nav class="menuL">
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="#!/page_about"><span></span>biography</a></li>
<li><a href="#!/page_portfolio" id="portmenu"><span></span>portfolio</a></li>
<ul id="submenu">
    <li class="subclass" id="first"><a href="#!/page_wine">Wine</a></li>
    <li class="subclass" id="second"><a href="#!/page_landscape">Landscape</a></li>
    <li class="subclass" id="third"><a href="#!/page_divers">Divers</a></li>
</ul>
</ul>
</nav>
<nav class="menuR">
<ul id="menu2">
<li><a href="#!/page_galleries"><span></span>galleries</a></li>
<li><a href="#!/page_contacts"><span></span>contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Here is the Javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('nav a').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('nav').find('.activeAnchor').removeClass('activeAnchor');
        $(this).addClass('activeAnchor');
      });
    });
```

and here is my CSS to go with the Javascript.

```
a.activeAnchor {
  color:red;
}
```

As the title mentions, this only effects the submenu. When I hover over portmenu (portfolio) and if I click a submenu item, then the submenu link I clicked changes to red and if I click another submenu item, it changes, so that works. However, if I click a non submenu item (a normal navigation bar li), it doesn't change. Any idea on why it is only effecting the submenu? Also, if I click one of the submenu items, I want portmenu (portfolio) to be highlighted instead of the submenu item, I'm not too good in Javascript so if someone can help me out with that, that would be great!

Comment: Do you want to use javascript for this? you can have the same effect witout javascript by using css

Comment: How would I use CSS for it? I would use anything, I thought Javascript was the only way to go. Are you talking about using a:active? Because a:active only changes the element / link for a brief moment while it is active, it doesn't change it until another link in the navigation bar is clicked, unless you know a way how to do it, that would be great.

Comment: I thought you wanted to change the color on hover, sorry.

Comment: No worries, that's fine

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
$(this).closest('nav').find('.activeAnchor').removeClass('activeAnchor');
```

...will only remove the `'activeAnchor'` class from elements within the same `<nav>` element as the item just clicked, but your top-level menus are divided into two `<nav>` elements. You could do this instead:

```
$('.activeAnchor').removeClass('activeAnchor');
```

...to remove the active class from any element that had it.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/B8EPS/

Or just limit it to ones with some `<nav>` element anywhere on the page:

```
$('nav .activeAnchor').removeClass('activeAnchor');
```

(Or whatever other combination actually matches the html structure you are using.)

Comment: Hm, I get what you are saying, but the problem is, even when replacing the code(s) you provided with my code, removing the class works, it's adding the class and getting the color of the navigation bar links to change which doesn't work. Only the color for items in submenu change correctly, the items in the actual navigation bar menu do not change color when clicked so I'm guessing the class isn't being added to the items not in submenu for some reason.